# Proof: $\nabla^2$ is invariant under rotation.

Tags: calculus

We are to show that $\nabla^2$ under rotation is invariant. In other words, $$ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial u^2} $$ is true, where $(u,v)$ is a rotated basis relative to the $x-y$ plane. My attempt is as follows $$\nabla^2 \equiv \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}
 \end{pmatrix} $$ We then define the rotation matrix $$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos{\theta} & \pm\sin{\theta}  \\
  \mp{\sin{\theta}} & \cos\theta
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Where $0<\theta\leq\pi$. Such that $\nabla^2$ under the rotation would become: $$ \nabla_1^2 = M\nabla^2 $$ However, this leads to a $2\times 1$ matrix which doesn't seem to simplify and equate to $ \nabla^2$. Is this approach legitimate or even correct? Can it be done by rotational matrices or is another method required? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = x\cos \theta - y \sin \theta$ and $v = x\sin \theta + y \cos \theta$. Then $$f_x = f_u u_x + f_v v_x = f_u \cos \theta + f_v \sin \theta$$
$$f_y = f_u u_y + f_v v_y = -f_u\sin \theta + f_v \cos \theta$$ Therefore \begin{align}f_{xx} &= (f_x)_u u_x + (f_x)_v v_x = (f_u \cos \theta + f_v \sin \theta)_u\cos \theta + (f_u \cos \theta + f_v \sin \theta)_v \sin \theta \\
&= f_{uu} \cos^2 \theta + f_{vu}\sin \theta \cos \theta + f_{uv}\cos \theta \sin \theta + f_{vv}\sin^2 \theta\\
&= f_{uu}\cos^2 \theta + 2f_{uv}\sin\theta \cos \theta + f_{vv}\sin^2\theta
\end{align}

and by a similar argument, $$f_{yy} = f_{uu}\sin^2 \theta - 2f_{uv}\sin \theta \cos \theta + f_{vv} \cos^2 \theta$$ Hence $$f_{xx} + f_{yy} = f_{uu}(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) + f_{vv}(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2 \theta) = f_{uu} + f_{vv}$$

Comment: I see, the immediate thing that occurred to me when I saw this question was rotational matrices. I'm guessing this isn't a valid way to solve the problem?

Comment: @bigman: the rotational matrices are implicit in this computation (cf. my answer, which is in essence the same)

Comment: @bigman you wanted to prove that the Laplacian is invariant under rotation. The expressions for $u$ and $v$ can be written $$\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$ This is what you were trying to express in the body. I just multiplied the matrices to find expressions of $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, which is necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now! Many thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is twice continuously differentiable. Let $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ a vector of unit length and $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ a position. What is the second derivative of $f$ in the direction of $w$ at $x$? It is: $(t \mapsto f(x + t w))''(0)$, which you can check to be
$$
w^T 
H_f(x)
w
$$
where $H_f(x)$ is the [Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).

In particular, take $w = e_1$ and $w = e_2$, and add them up -- you get $\nabla^2 f(x)$:
$$
\nabla^2 f(x)
=
e_1^T H_f(x) e_1
+
e_2^T H_f(x) e_2
.
$$

What happens if we take any orthonormal system $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, say $u = M e_1$ and $v = M e_2$ with a rotation matrix $M$? Then
$$
u^T H_f(x) u + v^T H_f(x) v
=
(M e_1)^T H_f(x) (M e_2) + (M e_2)^T H_f(x) (M e_2)
=
\nabla^2 f(x)
.
$$

The last equality is a matter of computation (compute $M e_i$ first).
And the term on the left is the sum of second derivatives at $x$ in the direction of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit imprecise about what "invariance" means here.

Define
$$
\pmatrix{u(x,y)\\ v(x,y)} = M \pmatrix{x\\y}
$$
What we want to show, then, is that
$$
\newcommand{\pwrt}[2]{\frac{\partial^2 #1}{ \partial #2^2 }}
\pwrt fx(x,y) + \pwrt fy(x,y) = \pwrt fu (u(x,y),v(x,y)) + \pwrt fv(u(x,y),v(x,y))
$$

Also, your approach is *not* correct.